# Could you help me identify this photograph that was taken shortly after World War 2?

Tags: world-war-two, 20th-century, photography

Could you help me identify this photograph?

[image]

All I know is that it was taken shortly after World War 2.

Comment: Welcome to the site. That's a kind of fun question/puzzle that is also nice to have here.

Comment: Could it be the NAZI Nurenburg trials? The military police men?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd say it's the [International Military Tribunal for the Far East](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Military_Tribunal_for_the_Far_East) (IMTFE or Tokyo Trials) from 1946. Compare e.g. the wall pattern elements between your picture and this one (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IMTFE_court_chamber.jpg)):

[image]

Comment: It's quite clearly the left-hand wall in this photo.  +1

Comment: Yup. The bench rows are even identical.

Comment: +1. The wall patterns are actually a mirror image, but that's just because this image has been flipped (check out the MP arm bands).

Answer (score 4):

It is the International Military Tribunal for the Far East.

Check the wall pattern and light:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IMTFE_court_chamber.jpg

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Military_Tribunal_for_the_Far_East